# Accessing the remote class method to resolve cyclic dependency

Tags: java, scala, maven, design-patterns, akka

[image: cyclic Dependency]
I am working with multimodule maven project, where I am facing the cyclic dependency between the `driver(module A) and actors(module B)`

> Actors module has a common creation of actor system which should be
>   common for all the actors across the project

driver uses *ActorSystem* to create an *ActorRef*  for some client-side API calls hence there is a dependency of `Module B on Module A`.
Also `Actor A` calls the method of driver class, which needs the dependency of `Module A on Module B.`

> So it turns out to be cyclic dependency where Module A needs Module B
>   and vice versa

I was looking for the solution where I could eliminate the dependency of Module A on B, as I want the Module B should not be dependent on any module.
If there can be any way by which I could access the method in the driver class indirectly that could help in eliminating the cause of cyclic dependency.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with your design. Its better if you could re-design the software so that the common things that will be used in both modules (A and B) should be in a different module, say COMMON MODULE. Then what you have to do is add that common module dependency to both your module A and B so that you can use common functions in both modules. 
And for the question you asked, " If there can be any way by which I could access the method in the driver class indirectly that could help in eliminating the cause of cyclic dependency." No you cant do it straightaway, if you are thinking of doing something like that, it should be like service communication. Then again it will add unnecessary network hops which we do not want. So the best thing is to re-design your software and eliminate cyclic dependencies.,

Comment: Cant we load the dependencies in classpath and access it thorough scala reflection?